# How to apply operator of data according to the time of subscribtion in rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

i have some problem about rxjava.

We want to collect different data depending on when the subscribe function is called.

data`ll comes in in the order of 1 to 9.

One subscribe function is called before inserting data. (called `Sub1`)

Another subscribe function is called after inserting data. (called `Sub2`)

A value of 4 will be the trigger. `Sub1` ignores this value, and `Sub2` merges the previous value when this value comes in.

detail logic is like below.

```
public void someTestFunc() {

    ReplaySubject<Integer> subject = ReplaySubject.create();

    Observable ob = Observable.somefilterOperation(...);

    ob.subsribe(res -> {
         // this is Sub1
         // data is output 1~3 5~9
         // 4 value is skipped. cause 4 is only use trigger.
         // output is 1,2,3, 5,6,7,8
         System.out.println("Subscribtion Before OnNext " + res);
    });

    for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
       ob.onNext(i); // data input 1~9
    }

    ob.subsribe(res -> {
         // this is Sub2
         // 4 value is trigger value.
         // 1~3 value is added by some function. ex "reduce", "scan"
         // output is 6(1~3 data added), 5, 6, 7, 8
         System.out.println("Subscribtion After OnNext " + res);
    });

}
```

```
Subscribtion Before OnNext 1
Subscribtion Before OnNext 2
Subscribtion Before OnNext 3
// 4 is skip cause that value is trigger
Subscribtion Before OnNext 5
Subscribtion Before OnNext 6
Subscribtion Before OnNext 7
Subscribtion Before OnNext 8

Subscribtion After OnNext 6 // this value is reduce value from 1 to 3 values
Subscribtion After OnNext 5
Subscribtion After OnNext 6
Subscribtion After OnNext 7
Subscribtion After OnNext 8
```

Is it possible to create a function called `somefilterOperation`?

Comment: You mean like `filter()`? That methods allows you to filter elements from the observable, like the `4` you don't want.

Comment: no. filter just filtering observable data when use pipe. i mean i want to handle observable data when Subscription timeing change.

Comment: Why not use `filter(it -> it != 4)` before/at your subscription for `Sub1`? You get any value but the value `4`, which you don't want. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you are trying to do, it looks like some information is still missing.